# Java GUI - JPanels, JFrames, JButtons

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to open a window that has both an `image` and `buttons` in it. But I can't seem to figure out how to add the button. The image displays great and the menu works fine, but no matter where I add the button (into the `JLabel`, `JPanel`, or `JFrame`), it doesn't ever show...

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI myGUI = new GUI();
    myGUI.show();
}
```

**GUI class:** openImage is called when using the menu. The image then displays, but no button.

```
private JFrame myFrame;
private JPanel myPanel;
private JLabel myLabel;
public GUI()
{
    myFrame = new JFrame();
    initializePanel();
}

public void show()
{
    myFrame.setSize(600,600);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.addMouseListener(this);

    setupMenu(myFrame);     

    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}
private void initializePanel() 
{
       myPanel = new JPanel();
       myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
       //myPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
}
private void openImage(String fileName)
{
    try {
        myImage = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    

    myLabel = getJLabel();

    JButton button = new JButton("ButtonClick");
        button.addActionListener(this);

    myFrame.setContentPane(myLabel);

    myPanel.add(button);
    myFrame.getContentPane().add(myPanel);

    myFrame.pack();
    myFrame.setSize(600,600);
}
private void setupMenu(JFrame window) {
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
        open.addActionListener(this);
        file.add(open);
        menubar.add(file);
        window.setJMenuBar(menubar);
}
```

Comment: `myFrame.setSize(600,600);` is redundant. The `pack()` method sets the frame big enough to hold the preferred size of each component inside the frame (but no bigger). Also, where is the `setupMenu()` method? That might be a contributing factor.

Comment: @fireshadow52 - Thanks for the reply. If I take out the `myFrame.setSize(600,600);` after the `myFrame.pack()`, it only sizes to the image dimensions. I also added the `setupMenu` method my post.

Comment: I think you should switch the `myPanel.add(button)` and `button.addActionListener(this);` statement. If that doesn't do it, check your code and see if you have any lines or statements that could mess it up.

Comment: Can you add the whole source? I can't compile it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main issue is your **setting the contentPane to be a JLabel** -- don't do this! The contentPane needs to be opaque, needs to be built to be easily used as a Container and in your case, really should be a JPanel. JLabel I believe uses a null layout so it's no surprise that your code shows no button.  If you want to show a background image, make have myPanel constructed from an anonymous class that extends JPanel, override the paintComponent method in this class (calling super.paintComonent first in the method), and draw the image in this method. Then you can add components to the contentPane which will now use a FlowLayout (the default for a JPanel) and it will be opaque by default.

Also, if your goal is to swap items displayed in your GUI, use a CardLayout to do the swapping for you as this layout makes swapping components a breeze.

Comment: Thank you, that was something I definitely missed. I added myLabel and button to myPanel, and set the contentPane to myPanel. Now it works as desired.

Answer (score 4):

really don't know, depends of method(s) how you are added picture to the `JLabel, JPanel, or JFrame`, but maybe for simle Container that contains a few, only one-two JComponents is there crazy idea, without side effects, with idea to display picture and to add there JButton:

[JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) is very similair [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) to the [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html), and is by default translucent and very simple implements [Icon/ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html), then you'll only to call `myLabel.setIcon(myPicture)`

to the all of JComponents you are/could be able to add another JComponent by using some of [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) (Box, Flow, GridBagLayout)

Answer (score 4):

You tried to set the label as the content pane and then tried to add the panel to that image which doesn't make sanse at all.

Change it so you add the label to the panel and have the panel as content pane:

Like this:

[image: evidence]

Comment: I almost requested a code example, but it's _in the image_! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have this line which is the problem. It doesn't make much sense:

```
myFrame.setContentPane(myLabel);
```

Try instead:

```
myFrame.getContentPane().add(myLabel);
```